# Retain first matching element of array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array as follows:

```
['a=1', 'b=2', 'a=2']
```

I want to filter the array to that the elements are unique with respect to their first character. I want the result:

```
['a=1', 'b=2']
```

In regards to the above, `["a", "b", "a"]` becomes `["a", "b"]`.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's from the commentary documentation for Array#uniq:

```
b = [["student","sam"], ["student","george"], ["teacher","matz"]]
b.uniq { |s| s.first } # => [["student", "sam"], ["teacher", "matz"]]
```

So it appears that `b.uniq{ |s| s[0] }` would unique-ify an array by the first character of each string.

Comment: I had no idea you could pass `uniq` a block. Wow haha. Thanks, Phlip!

Comment: I didn't know it either. But my editor, RubyMine, lets me enter `[].uniq` and hit Control+B, and it takes me to the source, with its documentation, faster than Google could.

Comment: lainK, [Array#uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq) has permitted the use of a block for some time. [Enumerable#uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-uniq) made its debut in Ruby v2.4 and it too could take a block.

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity (thanks @Phlip for the input I have shamelessly stolen):

```
b = [["student","sam"], ["student","george"], ["teacher","matz"]]
b.reverse.to_h.to_a.reverse
#⇒ [["student", "sam"], ["teacher", "matz"]]
```

Comment: Internally, `uniq` also uses a hash to remove the duplicates. Although more like `b.each_with_object({}) { |s, h| h[s.first] ||= s }.values` where `s.first` is the return value from the given block.